# Magento 1.8 Reducing Inventory for Pending Order

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Does anyone know of the fix in magento to NOT HAVE inventory reduced if the order payment is not done. Currently, by default, it reduces the quantity by one even if user never completes the payment process.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy fix for this problem which covers every aspect of the problem. The best approach i can come up with, is:

Set a flag in session after user checks out

```
Event:
```

> sales_order_place_after

On order success remove the flag (orderId)

```
Event:
```

> ```
> checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action
> checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
> ```

On the next page load of the user you could check for the flag and cancel the order if it still exists, but you might not catch all cases, since there might be no page load by the user.

Another approach would be to write a cron mechanism clearing all pending_payment orders, which are older than n seconds, but it might not be fast enough to satisfy the customer if he tries to choose another payment method. This is where the fist approch would come in handy.

Of course, you should do this only if payment method is expecting instant payment - otherwise you never cant be sure if payment happen at a later point.

Comment: Thanks Mischa for your reply.. I will definitely try this out and shall post the results.... Really appreciate your time and efforts!